# Scripting tables from Sql 2008 Mgmt Studio

Tags: sql-server

I use the Sql Server Mgmt Studio to script the creation of our database and all entities. Recently we migrated from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008 and I'm now using the 2008 version of Mgmt Studio.

I'm noticing some small but annoying differences in its scripting support that are making it really hard for me to diff my existing 2005 scripts with new ones created in 2008.

Some of the problems I'm encountering are the tables being ordered in some indeterminate order (not alphabetical), and extra linefeeds after every GO command.

Does anyone know how to make the 2008 version of Mgmt Studio script the same as the 2005 version?

An added note, I've found that if I use the multiselect feature of the Object Explorer Details window I can get consistent ordering of tables in the resulting script, but if I use the Generate Script wizard I do not. The wizard only seems to change the order when I make schema changes, but it makes diff'ing changes much harder. Surely others are seeing this problem?

Comment: +1 I was having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 4):

If you go to Tools -> Options, open the "SQL Server Object Explorer" node and then select the "Scripting" node, there are several options to alter the way that scripts are generated, including "Script for server version" which can be set to "SQL Server 2005".

Comment: Unfortunately this option seems to have no effect on the scripting results for me. I still see indeterminate ordering of tables (and the order changes as I alter my db design) as well as the extra linefeeds. These two issues happen via the two methods I know of scripting tables (using the Generate Script wizard and using the Object Explorer Details pane to multi-select tables for scripting).